# how to download files in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to download a file in my website . `item.upload_attachment` contain the link of the download link url eg `localhost:8000/media/uploads/poppy.docx`. But i want the link to be clickable so that the user can download it. Is it possible to put it in a `<a></a>` tags
?

`index.vue`

```
<template v-slot:item.upload_attachment="{ item }">
     <span>
       {{ item.upload_attachment}}
     </span>
</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File Using JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: What you are looking for is to "How to download file in JS". Here is a link that will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yes, it is possible to put the link as HREF attribute for an A tag.

Comment: @IVO GELOV `<a href="item.upload_attachment">Download </a>` it doesnt work though

Comment: Try prefixing the `href` with a colon `:href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question:

```
<template v-slot:item.upload_attachment="{ item }">
                 <span>
                    <a :href=item.upload_attachment> Download</a>
                </span>
              </template>
```